# When should I close database connection?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm connecting to a MySQL database using

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

While reading through forums and tutorials it says that it is good practice (although not vital) to close a database connection as soon as you are finished with it. So my question is this: should I always add `$dbh = null;` when the last database operation has been executed?

Comment: Most webapplication will need access to the database at multiple points. Just leave it open and let it automatically close when the request is finished.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Even setting to `null` is not immediate, as it leaves tear-down to the whims of PHP's garbage collection.  I doubt it makes much difference in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections are implicitly closed when a script has finished executing. The only reason you may want to close a connection is if you plan on opening another one; even then, PDO supports multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: So does it mean you never need to close PDO? @DC_

Comment: @Eritrea Generally, no. There may be special cases but personally I have never had to close a PDO connection manually.

Comment: -1: The number of connections available is a finite limit and idle connections still consume resources, hence closing connections earlier increases capacity and reduces load.

Comment: @symcbean I did not say the number of connections was *infinite*. If you are trying to make more connections than your MySQL server allows, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In php you do not  have to often close the db connections. Because, after your code finished, web server closes all the connections to database, because the execution is ended. But throughout the execution time you should close it quite a bit, for security reasons. But if you created a e.g daemon, you have to close it, more often, for both security and memory reasons. An open connection is always dangerous for direct db attacks, and reserves some memory.

Comment: How does closing the connection make it more secure?

Comment: Let's say your don't close any connection that's made to MySQL and assume you have an application which includes many pieces and each piece can work separately, with db. Because of their separate execution, you will connect the db separately. And if you don't close any of them your will have some memory issues along the security ones. For example, if the MySQL reaches its maximum connection limit, your application will die. Every query to application, then, will be perceived like a DOS attack to MySQL. And eventually, your server will die, because of lots of unhandled mysql queries.

Comment: You do not open multiple connections. You open one and pass it to all the "pieces" that need it. If you need to open a lot of different connections in your application you are (often) doing it wrong ™

Comment: Different users and different db privileges?.. hmm. I'm sorry. This is a very specific case that I encountered with, and I responded it like it's a general thing. It doesn't belong below this post. Sorry that.